# getContentLength return -1 when i try to download zip file

Tags: android, urlconnection

i try to download zip file from server and show progressBar, but i get `conexion.getContentLength()=-1`. That's why i can't show progress dialog, the downloading works fine. My code is below:

```
  URLConnection conection = fileUrl.openConnection();
  conection.connect();
  int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I get -1

It is the expected behaviour, when the `Content-Length` header field of the response is not set. It is backend-side issue, not client side. As workaround you can display an indeterminate `ProgressBar` (the spinning one) instead of a determinate one

Comment: Ok, thank you, i will send your answer to backend-side developer.

Answer (score 3):

Try `HttpURLConnection` instead of `URLConnection` and set `setChunkedStreamingMode(100);`

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) fileUrl.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(100);
urlConnection.connect();
int lenghtOfFile = urlConnection.getContentLength();
```